# How to make Python Decorator NOT run when imported

Tags: python

I've decorated a method in Python. And when I import the module that contains the method, the decorator autoruns.

I realize that this is how decorators were made however Is there a way to have decorators NOT do this?

Comment: No.  The first time a module is imported the code in the module is executed - period.

Comment: how bout some code? what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If the decorator is defined *before* the module is imported, you could monkey-patch the decorator to replace it with the identity function, which might be close enough to not running the decorator. `decorator = lambda f: f`.

Comment: This sounds like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377); could you tell us what your *real* problem is?

Comment: It's not a real problem. Im making an API and I want all my functions to be wrapped around another function which is the handler for all my functions in my API. Ultimately, It looks nicer.

Comment: Decorators were designed to run when the decorated function or method is _defined_. It's possible to apply them manually afterwards -- is that what you want?

Comment: Hmm, then I can put a placeholder decorater that does nothing then redefine it after it has been imported?

Comment: Anyone have any work around ideas

Comment: It is still a bit unclear what you are trying to do.  Can you update the question with a simple example, including how you want to use the decorator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is to choose what decorator to apply at run time.  Something like this might work:

```
to_decorate = []

def decorate_later(func):
    to_decorate.append(func)
    return func

@decorate_later
def do_stuff(*args, **kw):
    print('I am doing stuff')
@decorate_later
def do_more_stuff(*args, **kw):
    print('Even more stuff')

def apply_decorator(decorator):
    for func in to_decorate:
        globals()[func.func_name] = decorator(func)
```

Then you can import the module and all the functions will be defined as normal.  `decorate_later` returns the original function unmodified.  You can call `apply_decorator()` to apply a specified decorator to all of the functions in the module that were registered by `@decorate_later`

Comment: Seems kind of hacky and not the "right" way, but I've also encountered this problem where I wanted to decorate a function only when module is run as main, and run without decorator when imported and this helped me

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what the [venusian](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/venusian/en/latest/) library does; you define your decorators according to their API, but the actual behavior isn't triggered until you do a "scan" of the containing module or package.

You don't even need to have a global app object to use venusian decorators; you can pass in the app object as part of the scan, and it'll get passed along to the decorator implementations.  So, for example, the same functions can be shared among multiple owners with only a single decorator, just by doing more than one scan.

This is what the Pyramid web framework uses for e.g. event registration, so that merely importing a module doesn't expect to need an app instance.  A good example is their [event subscriber](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/events.py#L16).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    #code
```

in the file, where code is all outside a method or class ( that runs when you import it).

Comment: But note that when you import the module, *none* of the things done by `#code` will be available.

Comment: you could put it into a function so it is usable.

Comment: If rewriting the module is an option, you could just remove the decorator.